# Angular update property with OnPush change detection

Tags: angular

With this code using changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default

```
export class HomePageComponent {
  constructor(
    private i18nService: I18nService
  ) {}
  get language(): string {
    return this.i18nService.language;
  }
}
```

angular update the view but using changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,

it doesn't so the question is:

How can update the view using OnPush?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the service of `Language` ?
Be more specific what you are waiting for ?

Answer (score 1):

OnPush will only run change detection once (on creation). And Angular then only triggers change detection when a reference of an @Input() property changes (or if an Event handler of your component gets invoked).
In your component I see no @Input() statements at all.

You can manually run change detection by injecting ChangeDetectorRef into your component and calling appropriate methods on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but "You can manually run change detection by injecting ChangeDetectorRef into your component and calling appropriate methods on it." I know that but I don't really know in this case where put the call

Comment: Since your service doesn't signal when something changes, you don't have anything to listen to, to know when the language changes. So either you change the service that it provides an observable that you can listen to in your components and subscribe to that observable to manually invoke changeDetection or you can periodically run changeDetection using a javascript timeout. An example can be found here: https://plnkr.co/edit/RfJwHqEVJcMU9ku9XNE7?p=preview&preview